# How process NTLM authentication in Unity3d

Tags: authentication, unity-game-engine, ntlm-authentication

How process NTLM authentication in Unity3d with UnityWebRequest.

I try this code (but always get response code 401):

```
private IEnumerator Test(string url)
{
    UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Head(url);
    var logPass = "login:password";
    webRequest.SetRequestHeader("AUTHORIZATION", "Basic " + System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(logPass));

    yield return webRequest.Send();

    Debug.Log("xxx webRequest.responseCode " + webRequest.responseCode);
}
```

Please any help!!!

Comment: Actually, that error is normal and part of the protocol. See [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chiranth/2013/09/20/ntlm-want-to-know-how-it-works/) and [this](https://www.innovation.ch/personal/ronald/ntlm.html) for how it works and how to implement it. By the way, it is a Get request not Head.

Comment: I think that UnityWebRequest encapsulates requests